# Yara Rule Project signatures autoupdate

Tags: linux, clamav

I'm using a CentOS SPAM filter appliance ( [eFa Project](http://www.efa-project.org) ) and while Yara is included, it doesn't seem to be downloading new signatures as expected using ClamAV/freshclam.

Does anyone have any experience configuring clamav to automagically download Yara rules from GitHub?  It looks like rule indices are present on GitHub that should be downloaded as well and used in some fashion to pull new rules as added, or at least be processed and added to the ClamAV configuration.

Comment: using the ClamAV-Unofficial-Sigs package...  looks like it "should" be pulling these...